# Complex numbers solving for all solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

1. Find all complex numbers $z$ such that $z + \frac{1}{z}$ is real
2. Let $a \gt b \gt 0$ be integers.  Find all the solutions in complex numbers to the equation $z^a = z^{-b}$

For the first one, I tried manipulating the equation $Re(z) = \frac{z + \bar{z}}{2}$ to equal $z + \frac{1}{z}$ but I'm not really getting anywhere.

Don't know where to start for the second.

Comment: The second equation holds if and only if $z^{a+b}=1$. There is a standard expression for the $n$--th roots of unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1

> Let $z=x+iy$ for real numbers $x,y$. Clearly, they may not be both $0$ given we are dividing by $z$.  $$z + z^{-1} = (x+iy) + \left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} - \frac{iy}{x^2+y^2}\right).$$
>   In order for $z+z^{-1}$ to be real, its imaginary part must be $0$. Therefore,
>   $$y- \frac{y}{y^2+x^2}=\frac{y(x^2+y^2-1)}{x^2+y^2}=0.$$
>   So, $y=0$ or $x^2+y^2=1$. That is to say, the imaginary part of $z$ is $0$ or $z$ lies on the unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, let $z=re^{i\theta}$. Then our expression is $re^{i\theta}+\frac{1}{r}e^{-i\theta}$. This simplifies to
$$\frac{r^2e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{r}.$$
Forget about the $r$ at the bottom. We want the complex part of the top to be $0$, so we want $r^2\sin\theta-\sin\theta=0$. This holds if $\sin\theta=0$ or $r=1$. So $z+\frac{1}{z}$ is real if $z$ is real (and non-zero) of if $z$ is on the unit circle.